# How to get React app to render, right now it loads but doesn't render

Tags: reactjs, express, react-router

I'm working on a react application, that works perfectly until it's built for deployment.
My repo is here:
 https://github.com/aiglinski/qr_app.git

I've tried for the better part of two days. I would post code, but at this point I'm so lost I wouldn't even know where to start.
The app does load. If you open the console all of the elements show, and I can manually enter different paths and those load, but nothing shows beyond a blank screen.

Thanks.

Comment: Please put a [mcve] *in the question*.

Comment: could you explain from you got problems

Comment: What tool are you deploying on? And is this a web app, or are you building a native app?

Comment: I appreciate your responses but I don't even know where to look anymore. All I have learned after the last few hours is that run I run the build specifically on port 3000 with serve -s build -l 3000 it works just like it does in development, but when it gets hosted or run in production mode without that specific port it loads but doesn't render anything.